# Apply style "cursor: pointer" to all React components with onClick function

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I would like to apply the style `cursor:pointer` to all React elements that have an onClick function.  I know I could do this to every element:

```
<a onClick={handleClick} style={{cursor:'pointer'}}>Click me</a>
```

or this:

```
<a onClick={handleClick} className="someClassWithCursorPointer">Click me</a>
```

But I'd much rather be able to just do something like this to apply the style to all elements:

```
<style>
 [onclick] {
   cursor: pointer; 
  }
</style>
```

But that won't work because there's no actual `onclick` attribute in the rendered HTML of an element when using React's `onClick` attribute.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/roj4p1gt/

Comment: If you're doing `renderToStaticMarkup` or `renderToString` then the `onclick` will not be rendered.

Comment: @I Stanley, I updated the question with a jsfiddle example.  It doesn't look like you're using React in your jsfiddle.

Comment: @limelights, I'm not using ```renderToStaticMarkup``` or ```renderToString```, but ```onclick``` still isn't rendered.  I don't think in any case ```onclick``` will actually be rendered with React from ```onClick```.

Answer (score 6):

I am not certain there's a good way to do this automatically without using some sort of mechanism that intercepts the creation of React elements and modifies them (or perhaps source level transforms). For example, using Babel, you could use [babel-plugin-react-transform](https://github.com/gaearon/babel-plugin-react-transform) and add a `className` to all elements with an `onClick` prop using something along these lines (warning: pseudocode):

```
export default function addClassNamesToOnClickElements() {
  return function wrap(ReactClass) {
    const originalRender = ReactClass.prototype.render;

    ReactClass.prototype.render = function render() {
      var element = originalRender.apply(this, arguments);
      return addClickClassNamesToApplicableElements(element);
    }

    return ReactClass;
  }
}

function addClassNamesToApplicableElements(elem) {
  if (!elem || typeof elem === "string") return elem;

  const children = elem.children;
  const modifiedChildren = elem.props.children.map(addClassNamesToApplicableElements);

  if (elem.props.onClick) {
    const className = elem.props.className || "";

    return {
      ...elem,
      props: {
        ...elem.props,
        className: (className + " hasOnClick").trim(),
        children: modifiedChildren
      }
    };
  } else {
    return {
      ...elem,
      props: {
        ...elem.props,
        children: modifiedChildren
      }
    }
  };
}
```

[Here's a quick example](https://bit.ly/1kSFcsg) of the second part working: https://bit.ly/1kSFcsg

Answer (score 0):

I had created custom function component

```
const EditIcon = () => {
    return <svg style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 21 21"><path fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M17 4a2.121 2.121 0 0 1 0 3l-9.5 9.5l-4 1l1-3.944l9.504-9.552a2.116 2.116 0 0 1 2.864-.125zM9.5 17.5h8m-2-11l1 1"></path></svg>;
};
```

and used it like this

```
<EditIcon onClick={onEdit}></EditIcon>
```

but the onClick event was not working

When I used the parameter props in functional components like this
and using spread operator used {...props} as properties then it started working, below is working example.

```
const EditIcon = (props) => {
    return <svg style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} {...props} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 21 21"><path fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M17 4a2.121 2.121 0 0 1 0 3l-9.5 9.5l-4 1l1-3.944l9.504-9.552a2.116 2.116 0 0 1 2.864-.125zM9.5 17.5h8m-2-11l1 1"></path></svg>;
};
```

Answer (score -7):

You can do that easily with css:

```
a:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: if you want to suggest anything, please use comments for that. 
Please see this [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)